# Espresso - click a single list view item

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I tried doing the following:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.single_row_text),  withText("Item1"))).perform(click());
```

But all I got is:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: net.test.android:id/single_row_text and with text: is "Item1")
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.ListView@410d6ab0

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=800, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+-->ActionBarContainer{id=16909032, res-name=action_bar_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=48.0, child-count=2}
|
+--->ActionBarView{id=16909033, res-name=action_bar, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}
|
+---->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=false, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->ImageView{id=16908838, res-name=up, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+----->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>TextView{id=16908845, res-name=action_bar_title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>TextView{id=16908846, res-name=action_bar_subtitle, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+---->HomeView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=127, height=48, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=false, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=19.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+----->ImageView{id=16908838, res-name=up, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+----->ImageView{id=16908332, res-name=home, visibility=VISIBLE, width=119, height=25, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=4.0, y=12.0}
|
+---->ActionMenuView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=480.0, y=24.0, child-count=0}
|
+--->ActionBarContextView{id=16909034, res-name=action_context_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=96.0, child-count=1}
|
+--->CustomDrawerLayout{id=2131362153, res-name=main_frame, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=704, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+---->FrameLayout{id=2131362154, res-name=main_content_frame, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=704, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
|
+---->NoSaveStateFrameLayout{id=2131362155, res-name=menu_fragment, visibility=VISIBLE, width=260, height=704, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=260, height=704, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
|
+------>View{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=260, height=1, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
|
+------>ListView{id=2131362159, res-name=browse_types_list, visibility=VISIBLE, width=260, height=703, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1.0, child-count=0}
|
+-->ActionBarContainer{id=16909035, res-name=split_action_bar, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}
```

I also tried a lot of onData stuff but they are all fail:

```
onData(allOf(is(AnyTextView.class), withText("Item1"))).perform(click());
onData(Matchers.allOf(Matchers.is(Matchers.instanceOf(ListView.class)), Matchers.hasToString(Matchers.startsWith("Item1")))).perform(ViewActions.click());
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withContentDescription("menu_item_icon")).atPosition(0).perform(click());
onData(hasToString(startsWith("Item1")))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.browse_types_list))
                .perform(click());
```

Any suggestions for this? Thanks!

**SOLUTIONS** (Updated)

It turns out to be a timing issue. I run Thread.sleep(5000) before executing the test and it worked.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this.

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view)).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

Comment: I've tried that too. But it turns out to be a timing issue. I run Thread.sleep(5000) before executing the test and it worked.

Comment: Espresso is intended to handle all the UI timings. Is some data loading before displaying list?

Comment: yes sure, that's why I came with this walk-around, but still not sure if there's better way to achieve this without using thread.sleep

Comment: Yes, there is. Espresso has registerIdlingResource API which allows to wait for some custom event occurs (e.g. async data loading). Here's a blog post explaining how to use that: http://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/.

Comment: is using onData(anything()) a good thing/practice? Should we not use some specific filters right here (though using anything() and appending filters later works super smooth :)  )?

Comment: @HasaanAli Depends on your needs. This is just an example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It looks like the dropdown view hangs around and espresso fails to find the spinner. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245935/android-espresso-and-spinners-click-issue-dropdown-view-not-disappearing

Answer (score 9):

The beauty of Espresso is in not dealing with all this 'timeout' mess.

Have you disabled animations as mentioned in Espresso documentation:

> On your device, under Settings->Developer options disable the following 3 settings:
>
> Window animation scale
>
> Transition animation scale
>
> Animator duration scale

?

Comment: And we can say NO Timeouts?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the layout ID of the ListView, you can still run an Espresso test on it:

```
// Perform a click on the 5th item of a ListView.
// anything() is a hamcrest matcher that always matches.
// It's useful if you don't care what the object under test is.
onData(anything()).atPosition(5).perform(click());
```

This will work on Dialogs and DialogFragments which are displaying a list of items. And you don't need to specify the ListView ID.

Source: https://github.com/shohrabuddin/Espresso

---

<sup>Note: To quickly add the imports for these methods, put the blinking cursor on the unresolved method, then do Android Studio ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for `"show context action"` or `"show intention action"` ➔ click on the result option ➔ A popup window will appear ➔ click on `"Import static method ..."`. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Context Actions". [More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). Another way is to enable `"Add unambiguous imports on the fly"` in the Settings.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach...

```
protected fun clickFirstNodeWithGivenTag(tag: String) {
    testRule.onAllNodesWithTag(tag, useUnmergedTree = true).onFirst().performClick()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
onView(withText("ItemName")).perform(ViewActions.click());
```